# is it necessary for a graph to have Hamiltonian path if it has a Hamiltonian circuit?

Tags: graph-theory, hamiltonian-path

is it necessary for a graph to have Hamiltonian path if it has a Hamiltonian circuit?
If not then please provide an example.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

Any Hamiltonian circuit can be converted to a Hamiltonian path by removing one of its edges. Therefore, if a graph admits a Hamiltonian circuit, it necessarily admits a Hamiltonian path.